# Use .profile environment variables in ssh session

Tags: ssh, environment-variables

I want to be able to ssh to some user(Linux), and use his environment variables that are located inside his .profile file in his machine:

```
ssh user@add "echo $VA"
```

And lets say user@add has an environment variable VA in his .profile file in his machine. How can I do that? From what I understand when I ssh into someone's machine I'm in 'non interactive shell' and I can only use the environment variables which located in /etc/environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh user@add 'source .profile ; echo $VA'
```

You want to use single quotes in your command otherwise you will fill in the value of VA  on the local machine **before** you connect to the remote machine.